# Is CheckMarx scan by .net solution possible?

Tags: checkmarx

We are using CheckMarx's `CxSDKWebService` to scan .net code by giving it a TFS folder path. This works in most cases since we've one TFS folder per solution.

We do have couple of scenarios where files of multiple solutions exist under one folder and CheckMarx has a hard time keeping scan results pertaining to specific solution. It would lump all files under on CheckMarx project and all other projects have almost no LOC. Understandably so because its entry point is folder and not .net solution.

Is there a way to do a scan based on a solution such that scanner will ignore all files in the folder that are not part of solution currently being analyzed?

1. File and folder exclusion is not only unmanageable but the dev team
   constantly keeps adding files to specific solutions under that
   folder. Managing exclusion list is a nightmare.
2. Reorganizing TFS structure to have 1:1 ration for solution:folder is
   not possible, either.

**Additional Info**

We're initiating a scan using CheckMarx API `ScanWithOriginName()`. Essentially, our question is about having this API call work on a .net solution such that the scan will ignore all files NOT belonging to given .net solution.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is possible via the Visual Studio IDE plugin - though I have not used it in quite a while so I am not completely sure.

Comment: Actually, we're looking for ways to do this via CheckMarx API call `ScanWithOriginName()`. I've updated the question.